# Javascript: Check if page contains a particular div

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

How do I check using javascript if the page I'm on contains a particular div... e.g `turtles`

Comment: `turtles` it's a id or class?

Comment: I'd like to check if it's either

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if(document.getElementById("divid")!=null){
  alert('Div exists')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have that div's id, you can do it that way:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById( 'turtles' );

if ( myDiv ) {
    //It exists
}
```

overwise, if it's a class, you'd better use a framework (jQuery here):

```
if ( $('.turtles').length > 0 ) {
  //it exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckExists() {
  var oDiv = document.getElementById("turtles");
  if (oDiv) {
    alert("exists");
  }
  else {
    alert("does not exist");
  }
}
</script>
```

The function must be located in bottom of page or called after page finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to point out that [**document.contains**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) is another way to do this.

`document.contains` is particularly useful if you have a web application whose components are rendered virtually before insertion into the DOM.